# How to decode hex-encoding produced by nginx in javascript

Tags: javascript, nginx, encoding, decoding

For a request containing an utf-8 character, the nginx logs are encoded as follows:

`GET /asdf?v=\xE2\x86\x92 HTTP/1.1`

where `\xE2\x86\x92` is the utf-8 character `→`.

Browsers encode the URL as `/%E2%86%92`, which I can easily decode with decodeURIComponent:

```
console.log(decodeUriComponent('/%E2%86%92')) // /→
```

However, I can't seem to find any method to decode the hex-escaped characters.

When I log the hex-escaped characters, it also has a weird output:

```
var str = '\xE2\x86\x92'
console.log(str) // â��
str // â\u0086\u0092
decodeURIComponent(str) // â\u0086\u0092
```

How can I properly decode these hex-escaped characters?

Comment: `decodeURIComponent("\\xE2\\x86\\x92".replace(/\\x/g, "%"))`? Assuming that your log doesn't contain plain `%` characters

Comment: @Bergi This assumes that the backslashes are escaped, which is not the case. Can you provide an example where \xE2 and not \\xE2 is used?

Comment: I was escaping the backslashes because I was writing string/regex literals in my example, instead of reading in the backslashes from a log file. I was assuming that nginx writes actual backslashes?

Comment: nginx simply writes `\xE2`, which means my strings also contain that exact content (i.e. no double backslash).

Comment: Yes, as I expected. `"\\"` is a string with exactly one backslash: `"\\".length == 1`.

Comment: So is `'\xE2'.length === 1`, meaning I can't replace \\x which brings us back to the initial question.

Comment: If nginx writes `\xE2` , that's 4 characters in the file, isn't it?

Comment: Ah, I get your point. You were right that the string actually contains the contents `\\xE2` after reading the file and converting it to a string. I can simply use your .replace method, thanks.